# Vectorization for temperature simulation

Tags: beginner, performance, simulation, matlab, vectorization

I'm new to Matlab and I would like to know tips in order to reduce the processing time of such program. The scheme of the actual code is very similar to typical C++ code and I would like to vectorize the for and if loops in order to decrease the processing time. The code is added just to make you know the overall idea of what I would like to obtain.

```
close all             %Tanca totes les finestres obertes
clear all             %Removes variables from memory
clc                   %Clears command window
tic                   %inicia comptador temps simulació

trans=fopen('trans_matlab.txt','wt') 

%Physical properties and geometrical data input
Tair=25;
Tinitial=100;
h=10;
k=5;
qv=500;
thick1=0.05;
thick2=0.1;
density=1000;
Cp=800;

%Parameters imput
max_error=0.000001;   %Error màxim a partir del cual no hi ha canvis en els resultats
max_iter=1000000;
r=0.9;
N=10;                 %Nodes paret1          
M=10;                 %Nodes paret2
Inc_x1=thick1/N;
Inc_x2=thick2/M;
num_t=23000;          %temps de realització
Inc_t=20;

%Initial map temperatures
t=1;
for i=1:(N+M+1)       %Hipòtesi inicial: tots els nodes tenen T i Ta = Tair                 
    T(i,t)=Tinitial;      %(N+M+1) pq no deixa començar a 0  
    Ta(i,t)=Tinitial;
end

%GAUS SEIDEL
while t<num_t
    %New instant
    t0=t;
    t=t+1;    
    for i=1:(N+M+1)
        Ta(i,t)=T(i,t0);
    end
    %Temperature calculation
    for j=0:max_iter                  
        for i=1:(N+M+1)
            if i==1
            b=0;
            c=k/Inc_x1;
            d=qv*Inc_x1/2;
            e=density*Cp*Inc_x1/(2*Inc_t);
            a=b+c+e;            
            T(i,t)=(c.*Ta(i+1,t)+d+e.*T(i,t0))/a;
            end
            if (i>1)&(i<(N+1))        
            b=k/Inc_x1;
            c=k/Inc_x1;
            d=qv*Inc_x1;
            e=density*Cp*Inc_x1/(Inc_t);            
            a=b+c+e;
            T(i,t)=(b.*Ta(i-1,t)+c.*Ta(i+1,t)+d+e.*T(i,t0))/a;      
            end
            if i==(N+1)
            b=k/Inc_x1;
            c=k/Inc_x2;
            d=qv*Inc_x1/2;
            e=density*Cp*Inc_x1/(2*Inc_t)+density*Cp*Inc_x2/(2*Inc_t);
            a=b+c+e;
            T(i,t)=(b.*Ta(i-1,t)+c.*Ta(i+1,t)+d+e.*T(i,t0))/a;
            end
            if (i>(N+1))&(i<(N+M+1))
            b=k/Inc_x2;
            c=k/Inc_x2;
            e=density*Cp*Inc_x2/(Inc_t);
            a=b+c+e;
            T(i,t)=(b.*Ta(i-1,t)+c.*Ta(i+1,t)+e.*T(i,t0))/a;
            end
            if i==(N+M+1)
            b=k/Inc_x2;
            c=h;
            e=density*Cp*Inc_x2/(Inc_t*2);
            a=b+c+e;
            T(i,t)=(b.*Ta(i-1,t)+h*Tair+e.*T(i,t0))/a;
            end
            %Error calculation-trobar l'error maxim de la matriu error(i,t)
            errort=0;
            error(i,t)=abs(T(i,t)-Ta(i,t));
            if error(i,t)>errort
            errort=error(i,t);
            else
            errort=errort;
            end
        end
        if errort>max_error
            for i=1:(N+M+1)
                Ta(i,t)=T(i,t).*r+Ta(i,t).*(1-r);
            end
        else
            break
        end
    end
    iter(t)=j;
end

toc
%Print Results
t=1;
fprintf(trans,'time\t T1\t TN+1\t TN+M+1\t iter\n');

while(t<=num_t)
time=t*Inc_t;
fprintf(trans,'%.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\n',time,T(1,t),T(N+1,t),T(N+N+1,t),iter(t));
t=t+1;
end
fclose(trans);
```

Comment: I don't think the `c++` tag is adequate in this question, since there is no actual C++ code involved.

Comment: Rather than having us reverse-engineer your code, it would be better if you could tell us what the recurrence relation is, or what differential equation governs the logic, using [meta-tag:mathjax].

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that you expect this script to process and its output?  It would help me out with reviewing this program a lot.

Comment: Hello all, i just add the code just to make you know the overall idea of what i would like to obtain. The fact is that i am a begginer and i would like to have an idea on how to vectorize the "for" and "if" code in order to reduce the processing time. I don't want at all to have it rewritten

Comment: When I open this in the MATLAB Editor, the Code Analyzer identifies many issues (see the orange underlines under the code and the orange lines in the vertical scrollbar), some of the performance-related. Fixing these would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the hints in comments, I would like to add the following:

1. Replace the abbreviated variables by useful names. This will increase the performance of your code reviewer.
2. Try to keep all your comments in English (see 1.).
3. Preallocate variables if you really want to write their value inside a loop. Even in C++ you would not write `Ta(i,t)=Tinitial;`.
4. Do you really need all `N*M*num_t` values? If not, you should only store the current and the last iteration.
5. Now try to begin to replace the repetitive statements like `Ta(i,t)=T(i,t0);` and the sourounding `for`-loop with a single statement. You don't need to replace all at once.
6. Split your code into a main function and one or more subfunctions. A recent Matlab itself may then increase execution speed of the loops.
7. You calculate `c=k/Inc_x1;` very often but neither `k` nor `Inc_x1` changes. Try to identify lines which can be computed outside of the loop. Maybe you need to introduce more variables (with good names!).
8. Replace the `while`-loop by a `for`-loop. It will be more readable.
9. Correct the indentation of your code. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>.
10. If you have a 2D object, then why not use a 2D array for this. If you really need the results for all times, then you should have a 3D-array. You may then initialize it with `temperature = zeros(M, N, T_max);`

If you made all this changes, feel free to present your new readable and beautiful code.